# Best approach for arithmetic and comparison of quantities with different signedness in C++

Tags: c++, casting, c++17, unsigned

I have code roughly equivalent, for all intents and purposes to the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
  auto number = 2;
  auto vec = std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4}; 
  auto number_location = std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), number);
  auto number_index = std::distance(vec.begin(), number_location);
  if (number_index + 3 >= vec.size()) {
    std::cout << "Too close to the end\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Where `number` can be an arbirary integer. I believe that, since `std:vector` is a random access container, `std::distance` can potentially output a negative value, and the value deduced by `auto` is, thus, signed, but **for this specific code snippet** it is guaranteed to always output a positive or zero value, no matter what value is given for `number`. Since number_index is signed, when performing the comparison `number_index + 2 > vec.size()` my compiler emits a warning (I'm compiling this with g++ 9.3, with flags `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++17`):

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:10:24: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘long int’ and ‘std::vector<int>::size_type’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
   10 |   if (number_index + 3 >= vec.size()) {
      |       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My question is: Is it a sound approach to do a static cast, maybe `static_cast<long>(vec.size())` or `static_cast<std::vector<int>::size_type>(number_index)`, or is there a better way to deal with code like this, where distances between unsigned values that "may in general be signed but for the case of interest are not signed" pop up?

Comment: `if(vec.size() < 3 || number_index > vec.size() - 3)`?

Comment: Yeah, nevermind

Comment: Second try: Try `if (vec.end() - number_location < 3) ...`

Comment: answer to the question in the title is [`std::cmp_less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp) and its relatives

Comment: Maybe I should have clarified a bit more, I tagged the question C++17, `cmp_less` is pretty nice, but it is C++20 according to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/intcmp

Comment: @NathanOliver you are right, this works in my specific situation. Is the answer to the general question then "play with the algebra around until it works"? Its not very satisfying but I would take it.

Comment: @Ignacio That's my advice.  Mixing signed and unsigned number is just best to be avoided if at all possible.  Even if you know you'll never get a negative number, it's just safer to avoid it if possible.  One day someone might add something where the number does become negative, and then the code breaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ***know for sure*** that the value of the (formally) *signed* variable will not be negative, then the safest way to avoid the warning would be to cast that to a `size_t` type, because unsigned types have a higher maximum value than signed types of the same size. Also, on most platforms, `ptrdiff_t` (the deduced type of your `number_index`) will be the same size as the `size_t` type.

Casting an unsigned value to a signed type (of the same size) is less safe, as there is the possibility of overflow.

So, this would likely be a safe cast:

```cpp
    if (static_cast<size_t>(number_index) + 3 >= vec.size()) {
        std::cout << "Too close to the end\n";
    }
```

Comment: On most platforms though, you are not likely to reach the size of vector that overflows when cast to the signed of the same size.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev Indeed, that is *very* unlikely; however, the cast from signed->unsigned is still safer, generically. One could even use `uintmax_t` in place of `size_t`.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal is to compare a position to a size, and avoid this warning without using a cast, then one way would be to consistently use the same `distance` metric to determine the size.

```
auto size = std::distance(vec.begin(), vec.end());
if (number_index + 3 >= size) {
  std::cout << "Too close to the end\n";
}
```

If you have the option, however, you may want to modify your comparison logic to work directly with the iterators instead of using the size. In this case, doing so better communicates the intention of the printed message.

```
if (vec.end() - number_location <= 3) {
  std::cout << "Too close to the end\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For such cases, I would suggest using a signed integral type variable to capture the size first before the comparison statement(s).

```
long size = vec.size();
if (number_index + 3 >= size) {
```

If you expect the size of the vector too large to fit into a `long`, you can use the signed type corresponding to `std::vector::size_type` to make it more robust.

```
std::make_signed_t<std::vector<int>::size_type> size = vec.size();
if (number_index + 3 >= size) {
```

Comment: This could have UB.  `long` might only be 32 bits wide while `size()` could, and normally is, 64 bits wide

Comment: @NathanOliver, that is a concern if the size of the vector is going to be too large to fit into a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

`std::ssize(vec)` is available since C++20

Comment: It's tagged [tag:c++17] though

Comment: Still helpful for others that might this later on down the road when C++20 and above is more prevalent.